# PersistentVolume is invalid: spec.csi: Forbidden: may not specify more than 1 volume type

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, aws-fargate, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I'm trying to deploy a helm chart for postgres in aws Fargate. But i receive this error:

Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: PersistentVolume "postgres-pv-volume" is invalid: spec.csi: Forbidden: may not specify more than 1 volume type

PV

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-volume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: {id}
  hostPath:
    path: '/mnt/data'
```

PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

storageClass

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
```

In Deployment:

```
spec:
      volumes:
        - name: postgresdb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

...

```
volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgresdb
```

Comment: You shouldn't usually need to manually create the PersistentVolume, and you might try deleting that object entirely from your Helm chart.  If you need to keep it, the error is that you can't both have `csi:` and `hostPath:` volume types, but `hostPath:` is usually incorrect in Kubernetes (doubly so on Margate) and you can delete that section.

Comment: Yes ok, i deleted host path. Now kubectl describe pod say: Successfully assigned default/postgres-... to fargate-ip-.....eu-west-1.compute.internal

Comment: Bu then i got  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pv-volume" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not mount "fs-...:/" at "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/.../volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/pv-volume/mount": mount failed: exit status 1
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t efs -o accesspoint=fsap-...,tls fs-...:/ /var/lib/kubelet/pods/.../volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/pv-volume/mount
Output: Failed to resolve "fs-....efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" - check that your file system ID is correct, and ensure that the VPC has an EFS mount target for this file system ID.

Comment: I double check the id and is correct: IdFileSystem::IdAccessPoint is the same in csi: volumeHandle and on aws